# Insert object into multidimensional array in Meteor MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, multidimensional-array, meteor

I'm learning Meteor and I am having difficult understanding the MongoDB. I have a collection called Menu that looks like this:

```
    id:123,
    cat:'starters',
      details:{[
        item:'nachos',
        price:'3.99',
        desc:'chips & queso'
      ]}
```

I would like to add another item to that collection to equal:

```
    id:123,
    cat:'starters',
    details:{[
      item:'nachos',
      price:'3.99',
      desc:'chips & queso'
    ],[
      item:'calamari',
      price:'4.99',
      desc:'fried calamari'
]}
```

My code looks like this:

```
Menu.upsert({_id:'123'},{$push:{details:[{item:'calamari'},{price:'4.99'},{desc:'fried calamari'}]}});
```

I have also tried using "update" but I just get a "Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array" error for both.

**UPDATE**
Thank you Sindis, you were correct and I was able get this working.

I made a new collection called Menu2 like this.

```
    id:54,
    cat:'starters,
    details:[{
        item:'nachos'
        price:'3.99'
      }]
```

Then used "update" as suggested:

```
Menu2.update({id:'54'},{$push:{details:{item:'calamari',price:'4.99'}}});
```

And I got this!

```
    id:54,
    cat:'starters',
    details:[{
      item:'nachos',
      price:'3.99'
    },{
      item:'calamari',
      price:'2.99'
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think it should look more like this:

```
Menu.upsert({_id:'123'},{$push: {details: {item:'calamari', price:'4.99', desc:'fried calamari'}}});
```

The individual sections of the object your pushing don't need surrounding by an object and the update / upsert is already expecting an object to go into an array so there is no need for the square brackets.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: Thanks your answer, however; still no luck, I get the same error.

Comment: To do so, definition of details must be [], not {}. So first record should be like this : `details:[{
      item:'nachos',
      price:'3.99',
      desc:'chips & queso'
    }]` . Now you created an array, and you can push objects inside of it, {} is just an object in Mongo if I'm correct. Oh and also, try updating it, not upserting.